# What dB language would be fast and stable for a big database?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Which dB language would be good for greater social media like databases? I have used PHP5/MySQL till now, but never for anything really big. I was thinking about MongoDB/Node.js/Mongoose combination to use with a ReactJS app. Can it be that PHP5/MySQL can do a job like that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how big is big?

Comment: To take the most extreme approach, let's say 100M user dB, every user can upload videos, send pictures to other users and chat.

Comment: while you can plan like that, no one in software development does. You start with something you know and is manageable and change as needed. faebook started with free mysql. Design, development and  hosting of something for 100m users would not be a good use of your current resources

Comment: Well, that's pretty much true what you're saying, but I always prepare for the most horrible, extreme & bizarre thing.. So your suggestion is to start with PHP/MySQL dB?

Comment: well in that case expect to pay millions a month for hosting hardware you dont need - best of luck;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go for `greater social media like databases` , relational databases might not actually solve the purpose.

Go for something like a graph database. With implementation of nodes and edges and linked list, its performance is exponentially better than other databases.

Visit the official site of **[Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/product/)** - a free and extremely popular graphDB to begin with.

[image: Screenshot taken from **Graph 2e Neo4j, pg21]

Screenshot taken from **Graph Databases Neo4j 2e, pg21** (available for free download on the website mentioned above)

Comment: Looks very interesting and exciting from the documentation, definitely new to me.. I will probably go for that. What's the learning curve compared to SQL? (MySQL took me 2 hours to get comfortable in and to be able to do most of the things I need with it).

Comment: your Neo4j link is broken

Comment: @Maere: Do give it a try, it's indeed interesting. Although this might take a li'l more time to brush up as compared to MySQL; but trust me it'll be worth the time spent. Go through the PDF available on their site. That'll be a good start.